# Anonymous comparator function in scala with deconstructed tuples?

Tags: scala

I have a list of tuples, that I want to sort ascending according to the second element in the tuple. I do it with this code:

```
freqs.sortWith( _._2 < _._2 )
```

But I dont like the ._2 naming, as I would prefer to have a nice name to the second parameter like `freqs.sortWith( _.weight < _.weight )`.
Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
scala> val list: List[(String, Int)] = List (("foo", 7), ("bar", 3), ("foobar", 5))
list: List[(String, Int)] = List((foo,7), (bar,3), (foobar,5))

scala> list.sortBy {case (ignore, price) => price }
res70: List[(String, Int)] = List((bar,3), (foobar,5), (foo,7))
```

A case extractor can be used to put meaningful names on variables.

Comment: Hey, I like your answer, and I do get that sortBy is shorter than sortWith. But what if I insisted on using sortWith, how do I express the case then?

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to repeat everything twice in `sortWith`, you can use `sortBy(_._2)` instead.

If you want to have a nice name, create a custom `case` class that has member variables of this name:

```
case class Foo(whatever: String, weight: Double)

val list: List[Foo] = ???
list.sortBy(_.weight)
```

It takes just a single line.

---

Alternatively, you can "pimp" the tuples locally:

```
class WeightOps(val whatever: String, val weight: Double)
implicit def tupleToWeightOps(t: (String, Double)): WeightOps = 
  new WeightOps(t._1, t._2)
```

then you can use `.weight` on tuples directly:

```
val list: List[(String, Double)] = ???
list.sortBy(_.weight)
```

Don't forget to keep the implicit scope as small as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works, but I was looking for how to do this with tuples, and write more expressive code, not classes.

Comment: @themathmagician [scala.Tuple2](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Tuple2.html) has exactly two member variables: `_1` and `_2`. If an instance has member `weight`, then it cannot be of type `Tuple2`. Since every value in Scala is an instance of some class, writing expressive code without classes is somewhat difficult.

Comment: Yes, but the question was specifically about tuples - not classes and accessing class members. Since they are part of the language, I would like to use them in a more expressive way. Seems that the case extractor  does the job. Of course, you are absolutely right, that expessive code without classes might be somewhat difficult !

Comment: @themathmagician Tuples *are* classes, they are just heavily privileged in the compiler. Your question contained syntax `_.weight`. The period operator `.` has essentially one single function in the entire language: it's for accessing members of classes (it can also be used to select members of packages that don't have explicitly defined associated package objects, but that's nitpicking). If you just want pattern matching on tuples, that's fine, but then it has nothing to do with accessing the class member `weight`.

Comment: Hi @Andrey, thanks for being helpful, but my question was about expressive access to tuple members, not class members. Now I know, that a case extractor is doing exactly what I had in mind. Wouldn't disagree at all about the usefulness of classes, but in my case the tuple it is not a natural part of my domain, just an interim result in a computation, which fits nicely into the "utility bag" called a tuple.